# How to set value before form load in ninja form

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have used following method shown on [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158000/grab-values-from-the-query-string-to-fill-in-hidden-fields-in-ninja-forms) to achive this.
But field is not populated with the value i pass.

```
function wpse_158000_populate_field($form_id,$myfield) {
global $ninja_forms_loading;

$my_id_field = 16; //put the id for your hidden field here

//Change the value that a field is pre-populated with.
$ninja_forms_loading->update_field_value($my_id_field, $myfield);
}

add_action('ninja_forms_display_init', 'wpse_158000_populate_field',10,"test");
```

but it didnt worked.

I have added this code in
ninja-forms-modal/includes/shortcodes.php

Comment: `$myfield` is never set?

Comment: this $myfield is set by fetching value from shortcode

Comment: in add_action i am passing value "test"